# How do I call a method for all objects in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

So I have an interface `Pet` shown below:

```
public interface Pet{
    void Eat();
}
```

Which is implemented by:

```
public class Puppies implements Pet {
    @Override
    public void Eat() {
        // Something gets eaten here, presumably
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Kittens implements Pet {
    @Override
    public void Eat() {
        // Everybody knows Kittens eats something different
    }
}
```

Hopefully, what I've done next is create an `ArrayList` of new pets:

```
public class PetList{

    public PetList(){
        ArrayList pets = new ArrayList<Pet>();

        Puppies spot = new Puppies();
        Puppies rex = new Puppies();
        Kittens meowth = new Kittens();

        pets.add(spot);
        pets.add(rex);
        pets.add(meowth);
    }

public static void main(String[] args){
    // No idea how to handle this bit
}
```

What I want to do next is go through and tell all my pets to eat. How would I do this?

Comment: `spot` is *a puppy*, not `Puppies`, by the way. Java objects are generally singular. Lists are plural

Comment: use, List pets = new ArrayList<Pet>(); not  ArrayList pets = new ArrayList<Pet>();

Comment: @cricket_007 `spot` is a *puppies*. The code says so! I believe in code; not in humans.

Comment: also methods in java [should be verbs, in mixed case with the first letter lowercase, with the first letter of each internal word capitalized.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main issue with your current code is that the `ArrayList` (`pets`) is **local to the `PetList` constructor**, which means that you can't access outside the constructor of the class `PetList`.

So, first, make `ArrayList` as an instance variable to the `PetList` class so that it can be **accessible** through an object even **outside the constructor**.

Then, you can provide an `eatAll()` method which iterates the `ArrayList<Pet>` and call the `eat()` method on all `pet` objects.

You can refer the below code and follow the inline comments:

```
public class PetList{
    private List<Pet> pets;//now this is an instance variable

    public PetList(){
        this.pets = new ArrayList<Pet>();//this list is not local now
        Puppies spot = new Puppies();
        Puppies rex = new Puppies();
        Kittens meowth = new Kittens();
        pets.add(spot);
        pets.add(rex);
        pets.add(meowth);
    }

    public void eatAll() { //method to invoke eat() on list of pets
        for(Pet pet : this.pets) { //iterate the pets list
            pet.eat();//call eat() on each pet object
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
          PetList petList = new PetList();
          petList.eatAll();//invoke the eatAll() method
     }
}
```

---

As a side note, I strongly suggest you follow the Java **naming standards** (`Eat()` should be `eat()` i.e., method names should start with lowercase) and consider **renaming `PetList` class to `PetsTesting`** (or something else) so that it will be more intuitive for the developers.

Last, but important point is that don't assign the objects directly to the **concrete class types** like `ArrayList<Pet> pets = new ArrayList<>();` or `Puppies spot = new Puppies();`.

The best practice is that you need to assign the objects to the interface types `List<Pet> pets = new ArrayList<Pet>();` or `Pet spot = new Puppies();`(which is called **code for the interface types**)

Comment: Thank you for spotting, typo mistake

Comment: Apologies. I'm aware of the naming conventions but clearly mis-remembered them.

Comment: no problem, you can upvote and accept my answer if it helps

Answer (score 8):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    pets.foreach(pet::eat);
}
```

Should make them all eat

Comment: Hi Odin, welcome to SO, when adding a code, format it with a tab or 4 spaces before every line of the code instead of the backticks. +1 for the "Should make them all eat" lol :)

Comment: `ArrayList` object is local to constructor

Comment: I was getting frustrated with writing code in the comment field so I wrote it in an IDE and copy pasted over ^^' I guess I could indent an extra time before copying next time

Answer (score 3):

> Which is implemented by:

You actually have to implement the interface, it's not enough to define methods in concrete classes. Here how you do it:

```
public class Kittens implements Pet {}
```

Since you have an interface, let the type of your instance be of type Pet, so instead of

```
Puppies spot = new Puppies();
```

that would be

> Pet spot = new Puppies();

I suggest to learn/continue to learn java fundamentals (Inheritance, Polymorphism, and other concepts).

Here is what you need to get it to work as you expect:

> Pet.java

```
public interface Pet {
    void eat();
}
```

> Kettens.java

```
public class Kittens implements Pet {
    @Override
    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("Everybody knows Kittens eats something different");
    }
}
```

> Puppies.java

```
public class Puppies implements Pet {
    @Override
    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("Something gets eaten here, presumably");
    }
}
```

> PetList.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PetList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pet spot = new Puppies();
        Pet rex = new Puppies();
        Pet meowth = new Kittens();

        List<Pet> pets = new ArrayList<>();
        pets.add(spot);
        pets.add(rex);
        pets.add(meowth);

        PetList.feadPets(pets);
    }

    public static void feadPets(List<Pet> pets) {
        for (Pet p : pets) {
            p.eat();
        }
        // Java 8 / Stream syntax.
        // pets.forEach(Pet::eat);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your current approach limits `ArrayList pets` to only the constructor, so `main` cannot access it.

This is how you fix that

```
public class PetList {

    List<Pet> pets; // should be private, though

    public PetList() {
        this.pets = new ArrayList<Pet>();
    }
```

And in main

```
// Should be using a getter, though
for (Pet pet : new PetList().pets) {
    pet.eat();
}
```

---

Other suggestion

1) Create some `List<Pet>` (or make your whole class a list itself)
2) Iterate it, and call that method of the shared interface

```
public class PetList extends ArrayList<Pet> {

    public PetList() {
        add(new Puppy());
        add(new Kitten());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PetList pets = new PetList();

        for (Pet pet : pets) {
            pet.eat();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't like your second suggestion. extending arraylist is unnecessary and should not be used here. you'd just limit yourself because you could not extend anything else now (if needed).

Comment: Composition over inheritance is better, yes, but it was just an example

Answer (score 1):

javaguy has provided the answer you might have been looking for, but since you seem to be new to the subject, here’s some more advice on your code:

If you want java to recognize your `Puppies` class as an implementation of your `Pet` interface, you have to explicitly state this in your class definition:

```
public class Puppies implements Pet
```

In your `PetList` class you initialize (i.e. create) your list and pet variables in a so-called *constructor*. That means that these variables are unaccessible unless you *create an object of this class*. You might want to find a guide on how to deal with instatiating classes. For now I suggest the following solution: Instead of writing a subclass and initializing the variables there, do it in your `main` method:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class PetList{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        //Initialize the pet list
        ArrayList pets = new ArrayList<Pet>();
        Puppies spot = new Puppies();
        Puppies rex = new Puppies();
        Kittens meowth = new Kittens();
        pets.add(spot);
        pets.add(rex);
        pets.add(meowth);
```

In order to feed the animals, you can then *iterate through* the list using the *for-each-loop*. (You should look this one up, too)

```
        //Feed the animals
        for(Pet p: pets){
            System.out.println("Serving a meal.")
            p.Eat();
        }
```

[Please also read the last point in the style guide below since this code won’t compile.] A quick introduction: This construct *iterates*, i.e. walks through all elements in the `pets` variable and stores them, one at a time, in the local variable `p`. Inside the brackets you can then perform any operation on this variable, in this case, invoke the `Eat()` method on it. See what the console outputs if you add the `System.out.…` and in your animals’ `Eat()` methods add `System.out.println("Kittens just ate.");`

Since you’re using an `ArrayList` here, you can also access the individual pets via their *index*, i.e. position in the list. Using a *for-loop*:

```
        //Feed the animals once more
        for(int i=0; i<pets.size(); i++){ // For each i which is greater or equal to zero and less than the size of pets,
            pets.get(i).Eat();  //Feed the animal in the i-th position in pets
        }
```

### A quick style guide

- Class names should be in their singular form, e.g. `Puppy` instead of `Puppies`.
- Method names should not be capitalised, e.g. `eat()` instead of `Eat()`
- You can tell the `ArrayList` (and mostly any other container) what kind of data you’ll feed into it. This improves *type safety* since it can check for errors which else would only be apparent if you run your code and it crashes.

Suppose you had another class for trees: `public class Tree { /* No Eat() method! */}` As your code stands now, this would be possible, but crash:

```
Tree tree = new Tree();
pets.add(tree);
for(Pet p: pets){
    p.Eat(); // Will crash if p reaches the tree.
}
```

But if you parametrize your `petList` like this

```
ArrayList<Pet> pets = new ArrayList();
Tree tree = new Tree();
pets.add(tree);
```

Java can detect the tree as an odd thing to add to a pet list. (Actually, Java wouldn’t compile the first instance either, but I think this is a nice approach to type safety.)